# User Location Finder

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've got an button that when it is pressed it goes to users location. Can't figure out what to put in so I can get the zoom on the users location.

The following code I put in my button.

```
@IBAction func Refreshbutton(sender: AnyObject) {   
    Mapview.setCenterCoordinate(Mapview.userLocation.coordinate, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I do it in Swift:

```
   @IBAction func CenterMapToUserLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
        let latitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!),span: span)
        tripMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: You saved my day thanks! Also do you know how to make the map auto zoom on the users location when the app starts up? i have put NSstring in info.plist and i've put this code:

Comment: func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation], _: [AnyObject] ) {
            
            let latitude = Locationmanager.location?.coordinate.latitude
            let longitude = Locationmanager.location?.coordinate.longitude
            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion (center:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!), span: span)
            self.Mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            self.Locationmanager.stopUpdatingLocation()